# Copy template from one SharePoint site to another

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Thanks in advance for your insights.

I created a Template page in one SharePoint site. Now I need to copy that Template page to another SharePoint site. I was expecting this to be very simple, but have not found a viable solution yet.

Here is my Template page...

`https://my_url.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite_365/SitePages/Templates/Documentation-Template.aspx`

This is where I need to copy it to...

`https://my_url.sharepoint.com/sites/my_other_site/SitePages/Templates`

NOTE:
My version of SharePoint is SharePoint Online.

I created `Documentation-Template.aspx` as part of an Office 365 group site. Not sure if that might make a difference.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Under the modern experience, you can only copy a site page to the same Site Pages library in the same site. You could vote on this idea in uservoice：

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35035618-add-the-ability-to-copy-a-modern-site-page-from-on

As a workaround, you could switch to classic experience. Then copy a site page to another site with the URL path to the other site's Site Pages library. Like this:

[image]

Comment: @michael-han-msft thanks for these details. I used the link provided to vote. For the workaround this is my error message: "mycompany.sharepoint.com refused to connect". I am thinking this is not technically feasible using SharePoint alone.

Comment: I just tested in my end. It also didn't work for me. Same error as yours. Looks like it is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

This still doesn't seem to be an option.
Here's a flow I made to accomplish this

[Manually trigger a flow and ask for SourceSiteURL, PageName, DestinationURL and FailAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOSXy.png)

[Init Integer variable for FailAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLdxn.png)

[Switch to set fail action from input to Integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhoDt.png)

[Copy file in SharePoint from sourceURL/SitePages/PageName to DestinationURL/SitePages/PageName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOhkJ.png)